# Mining own Pool - Error reading from socket

Tags: mining-pools

When I will mine on own pool, I get this Error.

First, my Claymore says 5-15 Shared found, like spamming this and than claymore says gpu 0 failed

The Server says that:

```
Error reading from socket: read tcp ***.***.***.**:8008->87.187.109.76:51101: read: connection reset by peer
```

Why? I don't find it... also my site doesn't work anymore, but I don't know why...
Says

```
Stats API Temporarily Down
```

Claymore Miner works on ethermine or other pools... so must be the server

Answer (score 0):

Change Difficulty in config.json